# React component wouldn’t accept children

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a **React** component written in **Typescript** called **GradientText.tsx**:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from "react"
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"

// Define a mapping of valid HTML tags and their corresponding JSX components
const typeMap = {
    h1: "h1",
    h2: "h2",
    p: "p",
    // Add other valid HTML tags here
}

interface GradientTextProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
    children: ReactNode // Specify ReactNode type for children prop
    className?: string
    type?: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
}

function GradientText({
    children,
    className = "",
    type = "h1",
}: GradientTextProps) {
    // Get the corresponding JSX component based on the 'type' prop
    const TagComponent = typeMap[type as keyof typeof typeMap] || "h1"

    return (
        <TagComponent
            className={`leading-tight ${cn(
                "bg-gradient-to-r from-primary via-red-400 to-pink-500 text-transparent bg-clip-text",
                className,
            )}`}
        >
            {children}
        </TagComponent>
    )
}

// Set defaultProps for className
GradientText.defaultProps = {
    className: "",
    type: "h1",
}

export default GradientText
```

This component is supposed to accept text along with an HTML tag name and color it with a pre-defined gradient. For example:

```
<GradientText type="p">gradient paragraph</GradientText>
<GradientText type="h1">gradient header</GradientText>
```

The gradient displays the expected output in the browser. However, in VSCode, it shows two errors:

> Type '{ children: ReactNode; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
> Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

Again, the text displays alright despite this error.

**UPDATE**

As suggested in the first answer below, added `extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>` to my interface, but the problems persist. TS still saying:

> Type '{ children: ReactNode; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
> Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

**UPDATE 2**:

One way to prevent the error completely without breaking functionality is to just use `type` as string with multiple `if`s to render the desired element:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from "react"
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"

interface GradientTextProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
    children: ReactNode // Specify ReactNode type for children prop
    className?: string
    type?: string
}

function GradientText({
    children,
    className = "",
    type = "p",
}: GradientTextProps) {
    const style = `leading-tight ${cn(
        "bg-gradient-to-r from-primary via-red-400 to-pink-500 text-transparent bg-clip-text",
        className,
    )}`
    // Get the corresponding JSX component based on the 'type' prop
    if (type === "h1") return <h1 className={style}>{children}</h1>
    if (type === "h2") return <h2 className={style}>{children}</h2>
    if (type === "h3") return <h3 className={style}>{children}</h3>
    if (type === "h4") return <h4 className={style}>{children}</h4>
    if (type === "h5") return <h5 className={style}>{children}</h5>
    if (type === "h6") return <h6 className={style}>{children}</h6>
    return <p className={style}>{children}</p>
}

// Set defaultProps for className
GradientText.defaultProps = {
    className: "",
    type: "p",
}

export default GradientText
```

But I was hoping for a way to DRY this algorithm. Instead of having to write half a dozen `if`s, I wanted to use a single array-like implementation to dynamically generate the invoked tag.

Comment: Why didn’t your `interface GradientTextProps` extend from `HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>`? If it did, TypeScript wouldn’t need to be told about `intrinsicAttributes` like `children` or `className` because it will now know that automatically and won’t complain anymore. JavaScript might not mind but TypeScript does mind a great deal.

Comment: `TagComponent` is just a string, it's not a component that you can invoke as jsx `<TagComponent>`, make it a function

Comment: @Normal I just noticed that now. It’s a `string` from one of `typeMap` with `"h1"` as default.

Comment: But the renders happens exactly as expected. For instance, `<GradientText type="p">gradient paragraph</GradientText>` does render a <p> tag without any problem.

Comment: What are you doing here? *`”// Get the corresponding JSX component based on the 'type' prop”`*. I suggest you ask another question to get a good solution to solve this over what you did there. I will help you but you have to ask another question.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78040798/dynamically-generate-html-element-from-prop-value-in-react-component

Comment: @UbiquitousUbuntu, That's because you have `noEmitOnError` set to `false`, even though you have a typescript error, the compiler still emitting JavaScript. That's the default behavior for most development servers such as nextjs, create-react-app and also Vite.

Answer (score 4):

To have an `interface` that allows your custom components to take custom props such as `type` as well as html attribute props or react-specific html props such as using `className` instead of `class`, you should ideally `extend` your `interface` from

```
React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>
```

This will stop the warning you are getting such that `children` and `className` will now be recognized as `IntrinsicAttributes`. TypeScript needs to know this somehow.

```
interface GradientTextProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
    children: ReactNode
    className?: string
    type?: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
}
```

Comment: The error persists. Please see the updated code in question.

Comment: The multiple `if` statements used is not efficient. You should ask this in another question.

Comment: I know it’s not efficient, which is why I was asking for an alternative. I tried the `type?: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements` as you saw and it didn’t help. Anyway, have asked a separate question. See if you can help.

Comment: I think your question was properly answered there by @sdgluck.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not that simple.
To reach your goal, we need to use something called `Polymorphic components`
Read more: [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/build-strongly-typed-polymorphic-components-with-react-and-typescript/)

Simple code like that, you have to defined a `React Component` like this:

```js
type TextProps<C extends React.ElementType> = {
    as?: C;
  };
  
  type Props<C extends React.ElementType> = React.PropsWithChildren<
    TextProps<C>
  > &
    Omit<React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<C>, keyof TextProps<C>>;
  
export const Text = <C extends React.ElementType = 'span'>({
    as,
    children,
    ...restProps
}: Props<C>) => {
    const Component = as || 'span';
    return (
        <Component {...restProps}>
            {children}
        </Component>
    );
};
```

And use this like this:

```
<Text as={'p'} className='someClass'/>
```