# Dynamically generate HTML element from prop value in React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React component written using Typescript. It receives three props:

1. `type`,
2. `className`, and
3. `children`

Its job is to return an HTML element based on the value sent through `type`. Here’s the component:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from "react"
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"

interface GradientTextProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
    children: ReactNode // Specify ReactNode type for children prop
    className?: string
    type?: string
}

export default function GradientText({
    children,
    className,
    type,
}: GradientTextProps) {
    const style = `leading-tight ${cn(
        "bg-gradient-to-r from-primary via-red-400 to-pink-500 text-transparent bg-clip-text",
        className,
    )}`
    if (type === "h1") return <h1 className={style}>{children}</h1>
    if (type === "h2") return <h2 className={style}>{children}</h2>
    if (type === "h3") return <h3 className={style}>{children}</h3>
    if (type === "h4") return <h4 className={style}>{children}</h4>
    if (type === "h5") return <h5 className={style}>{children}</h5>
    if (type === "h6") return <h6 className={style}>{children}</h6>
    return <p className={style}>{children}</p>
}

// Set defaultProps for className
GradientText.defaultProps = {
    className: "",
    type: "p",
}
```

So, the following usage:

```
<GradientText type="h1" className="text-7xl font-bold">gradient paragraph</GradientText>
```

Would generate:

```
<h1 className="leading-tight text-7xl font-bold bg-gradient-to-r from-primary via-red-400 to-pink-500 text-transparent bg-clip-text">
gradient paragraph
</h1>
```

When there’s no type attribute, the component defaults to `<p>`.

Here, I am using six separate `if` statements to map six different type values to corresponding HTML tags. I want to make it dynamic. So that the component could just look up the given `type` value against a set array and dynamically generate the appropriate element—`<p>` for `type="p"`, `<h1>` for `type="h1"`, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const htmlTagMap: { [key: string]: React.ElementType } = {
    h1: 'h1',
    h2: 'h2',
    h3: 'h3',
    h4: 'h4',
    h5: 'h5',
    h6: 'h6',
    p: 'p'
};

export default function GradientText({
    children,
    className,
    type = "p",
}: GradientTextProps) {
    const Tag = tagMap[type] || 'p'; // default your tag to <p>
    const style = '...';

    return <Tag className={style}>{children}</Tag>;
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Aside: JavaScript may not complain when using `string`s as component tags, but TypeScript will.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon Typescript shouldn't complain here because in `htmlTagMap` I am accepting type of only `React.ElementType`

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by utilising directly the [`React.createElement` API](https://react.dev/reference/react/createElement), which takes as a first argument the element type. The element type can be a function, in the case of a custom component, or a string for known HTML elements such as H1, H2, and so on.

With that in mind you can do something like this:

```js
export default function GradientText({
    children,
    className,
    type = "p",
}: GradientTextProps) {
    const style = `leading-tight ${cn(
        "bg-gradient-to-r from-primary via-red-400 to-pink-500 text-transparent bg-clip-text",
        className,
    )}`
    return React.createElement(type, { className: style }, children)
}
```